# Mongodb find with wrong result Int64 object

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

I'm using MongoDB 3.2.1 / python 3.4 / pymongo / pandas 0.17 (although the latter two are probably completely irrelavant to this question).

I'm having a really strange (and wrong) behavior with MongoDB find.

I have a collection, containing a document like this:

```
 {
        "_id" : NumberLong(-1819413477243867792),
        "targetentity" : "NODOGENERICO .ag.HP_BAR_DEG_APP_1",
        "tx" : false,
        "ocname" : ".oc.serv6",
        "specificproblem" : null,
        "saf" : false,
        "iscriticalnode" : null,
        "checkmask" : null,
        "notificationidentifier" : 1347592,
        "province" : null,
        "usertext" : null,
        "additionaltext" : "AAA Invalid Response",
        "director" : ".temip.madrids01_director",
        "problemoccurences" : 1,
        "usertags" : null,
        "managedobject" : "NODOGENERICO .ag.HP_BAR_DEG_APP_1",
        "isacceptednode" : null,
        "elementcode" : null,
        "state" : "Terminated",
        "probablecause" : "Unknown",
        "ran" : false,
        "counttotal" : 1,
        "locationcode" : "NULL",
        "problemstatus" : "Closed",
        "structurednotes" : null,
        "collection" : "serv6",
        "operatornotes" : null,
        "alarmtype" : "CommunicationsAlarm",
        "workinfo" : null,
        "perceivedseverity" : "Major",
        "core" : true,
        "eventtime" : NumberLong(1467342666000),
        "originalseverity" : "Major",
        "vendor" : "Several",
        "controlelementcode" : null,
        "outageflag" : false,
        "incident" : null,
    }
```

This "_id" it's basically a Hash computed using "hash" builtin method of Python 3.4.

The problem is that I cannot find any element with this id after I insert it.

I've tried (at this point I'm trying this on mongo terminal directly, but over Pymongo it gets me the same results):

> db.getCollection('unique_alarm').find({"_id": NumberLong(-1819413477243867792)}

and

> db.getCollection('unique_alarm').find({"_id": -1819413477243867792})

And for both I get this:

> Fetched 0 record(s) in 1ms

I thought the problem was about how I deal with NumberLong, but for field eventtime (which has the same type) I have absolutely no problem.

I.e., for the eventtime if I query:

> db.getCollection('unique_alarm').find({"eventtime" :
>   NumberLong(1467342666000)})

or by:

> db.getCollection('unique_alarm').find({"eventtime" :1467342666000})

Both these queries return this first document again, no problem.

**Any clues on what is happening? Why are the first two queries returning 0 results?**

More information on my trial and error:

- it doesnt matter if the field is "_id" or any other field, I cannot search for these numbers
- I'm inserting these documents using pymongo
- If I try to insert this document again (either using pymongo or the mongodb terminal), I get an error of duplicate key...

Comment: If any one is interested, my workaround was to converting the type to **string**. So basically, before inserting I'm converting the number to string, and then I search by a string value, and works perfectly. My conjecture is that there's some issue with some types of NumberLong and Mongodb searches (possibly related with the result of python hash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the answer could be trivial but all is connected with quotes `"` around value for number long.

Inserting data and querying need to be 'quoted'

```
db.sofia.find({"_id" : NumberLong("-1819413477243867792")}).pretty()

{
        "_id" : NumberLong("-1819413477243867792"),
        "targetentity" : "NODOGENERICO .ag.HP_BAR_DEG_APP_1",
        "tx" : false,
        "ocname" : ".oc.serv6",
        ....
}
```

[image: quotes]

Comment: it worked, thanks! Do you know why the other field 'eventtime' returned ok, even without the quotes? Shouldnt it returned 0 results as well? I guess that was why I never tried it with quotes.

Comment: it could be by javascript limitation in shell, but i'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

I think you're hitting some sort of limits within mongo NumberLong.

I've opened a mongo console and this is the output

```
> NumberLong(-1819413477243867792)
NumberLong("-1819413477243867904")
```

So I would assume that if you find by NumberLong("-1819413477243867904") you would magically find your record, which would probably prove that your hash is hitting some sort of mongo db limit if NumberLong.